# Calculating mixed strategy of $3 \times 3$ game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

### The Question

> We consider the following zero-sum strategic game in matrix form
>
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
>  & \text{A} & \text{B} & \text{C} \\
> \hline
> A & 0 & +\epsilon & -\delta \\
> B & -\epsilon & 0 & 0 \\
> C & \delta & 0 & 0
> \end{array}
>
> where $\epsilon$ and $\delta$ are nonnegative real numbers.
>
> (a) Find all equilibria for this game (show your working) assuming $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $\delta \gt 0$.
> (b) Assume some probabilities for playing $A$ or playing $B$, both for focal player and opponent. Calculate the expected payoffs for each strategy.

### My Understanding

I am completely stuck as I seem to calculate that the strategy $(C,C)$ is a saddle point but then if we reduce it to the $2 \times 2$ game $(A,B)$ then $(A,A)$ is a saddle point therefore there can't be a mixed strategy correct?

Comment: You might get downvotes so before that pls show your working

Comment: No, there is a mixed strategy saddle point. If either player chooses the pure strategies $\ A, B,$ and $C$ with probabilities $\ 0\ $, $\ \frac{\delta}{\delta+\epsilon}\ $ and $\ \frac{\epsilon}{\delta+\epsilon}\ $, respectively, then his or her *expected* payoff is still $\ 0\ $ no matter what strategy the other player chooses.

Comment: I'm not sure how you calculated those probabilities for the strategies, how would you go about that?

Comment: I have written up the procedure as an answer,

Answer (score 2):

The game is symmetric (i.e. the payoff matrix is skew-symmetric) so you know its value must be $\ 0\ $. Therefore any optimal mixed strategy $\ \big(p_1,p_2,p_3\big)\ $ for the second player must guarantee that the expected payoff to the first player be non-positive. It must therefore satisfy the inequalities
\begin{align}
&\epsilon p_2-\delta p_3&\le0\\
-\epsilon p_1&&\le 0\\
\delta p_1&&\le0\\
&p_i\ge0&\text{for }\ i=1,2,3,
\end{align}
and the equation
$$
p_1+p_2+p_3=1\ .
$$
The second and third inequalities imply that $\ p_1=0\ $, while the equation and the first inequality give
$$
0\ge\epsilon p_2-\delta p_3=(\epsilon+\delta)p_2-\delta\ \ \text{, or}\\
0\le p_2\le\frac{\delta}{\epsilon+\delta}\ .
$$
Conversely, if $\ p_2\ $ satisfies this final pair of inequalities, $\ p_3=1-p_2\ $, and $\ p_1=0\ $, then all six inequalities and the equation are satisfied, so $\ \big(0,p_2,p_3\big)\ $ is an optimal strategy.

Therefore, a mixed strategy $\ \big(p_1,p_2,p_3\big)\ $  is optimal if and only if:

- $\ p_1=0\ $,
- $\ 0\le p_2\le\frac{\delta}{\epsilon+\delta}\ $, and
- $\ p_3=1-p_2\ $.